# TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard doesn't recognize certain parameters in my query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset, visual-studio-2022, tableadapter

I am setting up table adapters in an xsd file for my project in Visual Studio 2022. The problem I am running into is that, in my query I have parameters in my WHERE clause that are recognized by the table adapter and they work fine, I also have parameters in my ORDER BY clause that are not recognized.

For example I have a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE data = @data
ORDER BY @sortDirection AND @sortField
```

The problem is that the table adapter recognizes the @data parameters and I when I call the adapter in my DAO I can assign @data a value. However, it does not see @sortDirection and @sortField so when I try to assign them values (In this case I am assigning them to GridView.Attributes("sortDirection") and GridView.Attributes("sortField")) I get an error stating

> Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Function MyFunction() As MyDataset.MyTableAdapter.

Any assistance with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, [you can't parameterize sort column or sort direction in `ORDER BY`](https://dbfiddle.uk/XRTO4Mci) so the SQL could never be valid that way. I don't use adapters so I'm not certain, but I think you shouldn't be specifying those as parameters in the query text.

Comment: Think of SQL query parameters as being like VB method parameters. In VB, can you pass in an identifier via a method parameter, e.g. the name of a type or property? Of course you can't. You can only use parameters to pass in values. The same goes for SQL parameters. They can only be used to pass values, not identifiers, e.g. the name of a table or column.